# Windows 10 2004 Task Scheduler refuses to run task (silent failure)

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I am running Windows 10 2004 on a desktop computer. I created a task using the Task Scheduler GUI.

- Chose the option `Run whether user is logged on or not`

  - Checked the `Run with highest privileges` box
  - Checked the `Do not store password` box
- Added a single trigger to scheduled the task to run daily, with 2-hour randomization
- Disabled the option: *Start the task only if the computer is on AC power*
- Added three actions, similar to the following:

  - `bash -c "docker pull python"`

In order to test the task, I am right-clicking on the task and selecting `Run` from the context menu.

### Actual Result

The task does not run. There is no indication that the task attempted to run, or that the task has failed. I consider this to be a "silent failure."

### Expected Result

The task should run on-demand when I choose `Run`.

### Notes

To work around this problem, I changed the **Security Options** to `Run only when the user is logged on`. Now, when I manually invoke the task, it works successfully.

**Question**: Why doesn't the task scheduler run my task, when I am using the `Run whether user is logged on or not` option?

Comment: Perhaps change the executable to `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`. As debug, change the command being run to `echo` to a text file.

Comment: The issue isn't the actions. As you may have noticed, once I change the security options to run only when the user is logged on, the task works perfectly fine.

Comment: When a login exists, the environment of the task being run is different. Especially, the PATH environment variable may be missing or different. You shouldn't assume anything.

Comment: Yeah, but the task didn't even attempt to run. If the path to `bash` was incorrect, then the task would fail.

Comment: You cannot be sure about it. But it might also be `docker`.

Answer (score 0):

The physical logged on user must not be interrupted. When you choose those security options it logs in and runs in another login so programs will be invisible.

If you look on the History tab in Task Scheduler you will see it's run time and exit code if it sets one.